# Не могу добавить метод по редактированию данных в ListView через БД Realm

Tags: listview, android-edittext, realm, android-dialog, realm-database

Имеется активити, выводится список с добавленными числами через меню по кнопкам add и add random, при нажатии которых список заполняется цифрами
Нужно настроить редактирование этих итемов, чтобы была вохможность через itemLongClick заменить цифру списка на другую цифру, и сохранить ее значение.

```
public class ListViewExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Realm realm;
private Menu menu;
private MyListAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    // RealmResults are "live" views, that are automatically kept up to date, even when changes happen
    // on a background thread. The RealmBaseAdapter will automatically keep track of changes and will
    // automatically refresh when a change is detected.
    final RealmResults<Item> counters = realm.where(Item.class).sort(Item.FIELD_ID).findAll();
    adapter = new MyListAdapter(counters);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int i, long l) {

            final Item counter = adapter.getItem(i);

            if (counter == null) {
                return true;
            }

            final int id = counter.getId();

            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ListViewExampleActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("Title");

            Button button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.save_button_dialog);

            EditText edit = dialog.findViewById(R.id.edittext_dialog);

            //кнопка сохранения
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    //здесь хочу дописать метод по редактированию итема


                }
            });


            dialog.show();

            //здесь происходит удаление итема из БД через долгое нажатие, мне это не нужно
            /*realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.where(Item.class).equalTo(Item.FIELD_ID, id).findAll().deleteAllFromRealm();
                }
            });*/
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    realm.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listview_options, menu);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_normal_mode, true);
    menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_delete_mode, false);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            DataHelper.addItemAsync(realm);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_random:
            DataHelper.randomAddItemAsync(realm);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_start_delete_mode:
            adapter.enableDeletionMode(true);
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_normal_mode, false);
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_delete_mode, true);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_end_delete_mode:
            DataHelper.deleteItemsAsync(realm, adapter.getCountersToDelete());
            // Fall through
        case R.id.action_cancel_delete_mode:
            adapter.enableDeletionMode(false);
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_normal_mode, true);
            menu.setGroupVisible(R.id.group_delete_mode, false);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Сделал кастомный диалог custom_dialog.xml с  сохранением и отменой

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:inputType="" />

<Button
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/save_button_dialog"
    android:text="Сохранить"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button_dialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_dialog"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Удалить"
    />
```

Модель данных Item с методами по созданию, удалению и нерабочим редактированием

```
public class Item extends RealmObject {
public static final String FIELD_ID = "id";
private String title;

private static AtomicInteger INTEGER_COUNTER = new AtomicInteger(0);

@PrimaryKey
private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getCountString() {
    return Integer.toString(id);
}

//  create() & delete() needs to be called inside a transaction.
static void create(Realm realm) {
    create(realm, false);
}

static void create(Realm realm, boolean randomlyInsert) {
    Parent parent = realm.where(Parent.class).findFirst();
    RealmList<Item> items = parent.getItemList();
    Item counter = realm.createObject(Item.class, increment());
    if (randomlyInsert && items.size() > 0) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        items.listIterator(rand.nextInt(items.size())).add(counter);
    } else {
        items.add(counter);
    }
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

//метод по редактированию итема, не знаю как доработать его
static void update(Realm realm, long id, String title) {
    Item item = realm.where(Item.class).equalTo(FIELD_ID, id).findFirst();
    if (item != null) {
        item.setTitle(title);
    }
}

static void delete(Realm realm, long id) {
    Item item = realm.where(Item.class).equalTo(FIELD_ID, id).findFirst();
    // Otherwise it has been deleted already.
    if (item != null) {
        item.deleteFromRealm();
    }
}

private static int increment() {
    return INTEGER_COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
}
}
```

Класс помощник для работы с БД

```
public class DataHelper {

// Create 3 counters and insert them into random place of the list.
public static void randomAddItemAsync(Realm realm) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                Item.create(realm, true);
            }
        }
    });
}

public static void addItemAsync(Realm realm) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Item.create(realm);
        }
    });
}

public static void deleteItemAsync(Realm realm, final long id) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Item.delete(realm, id);
        }
    });
}

//здесь пытаюсь прописать метод по редактированию итема
public static void updateItemAsync(Realm realm, final long id, final String string) {
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Item.update(realm, id, string);

        }
    });


}

public static void deleteItemsAsync(Realm realm, Collection<Integer> ids) {
    // Create an new array to avoid concurrency problem.
    final Integer[] idsToDelete = new Integer[ids.size()];
    ids.toArray(idsToDelete);
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            for (Integer id : idsToDelete) {
                Item.delete(realm, id);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Адаптер для отрисовки холста

```
class MyListAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Item> implements ListAdapter {

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView countText;
    CheckBox deleteCheckBox;
}

private boolean inDeletionMode = false;
private Set<Integer> countersToDelete = new HashSet<Integer>();

MyListAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Item> realmResults) {
    super(realmResults);
}

void enableDeletionMode(boolean enabled) {
    inDeletionMode = enabled;
    if (!enabled) {
        countersToDelete.clear();
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

Set<Integer> getCountersToDelete() {
    return countersToDelete;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.countText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        viewHolder.deleteCheckBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (adapterData != null) {
        final Item item = adapterData.get(position);
        viewHolder.countText.setText(item.getCountString());
        if (inDeletionMode) {
            viewHolder.deleteCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    countersToDelete.add(item.getId());
                }
            });
        } else {
            viewHolder.deleteCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        }
        viewHolder.deleteCheckBox.setChecked(countersToDelete.contains(item.getId()));
        viewHolder.deleteCheckBox.setVisibility(inDeletionMode ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Рад любой помощи

Comment: Как то это не просто все у вас затеяно. На мой взгляд, зашаривать на листбокс надо ObservableCollection. На клик получать экземпляр SelectedItem, его менять как душа пожелает в вашей форме. Это по сути все :)

Comment: вы можете написать пример кода или дать ссылку на пример, я бы изучил

Comment: [изучайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138992/binding-observablecollection-to-wpf-listbox) в поиске поглядите, тема заежжена до дыр, как мне кажется :)